# Update user settings with and without password. Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I have *settings* form. I want make so that if password field is empty, update other attributes. 
Also I'm using *devise*. Are there some useful methods that might help me with this?

**form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@user, :url => url_for(:controller => 'settings', :action => 'update')) do |f| %>

    <%= f.label :email, 'Email' %>
    <%= f.email_field :email %>

    <%= f.label :mobile, 'Mobile' %>
    <%= f.phone_field :mobile %>

    <%= f.label :current_password, "Current password" %>
    <%= f.password_field :current_password %>

    <%= f.label :password, "New Password" %>
    <%= f.password_field :password, :autocomplete => "off"  %>

    <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirm New Password" %>
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>

    <%= f.submit "Update" %>                
<% end %>
```

**user.rb**

```
  validates :password, length: {minimum: 4}, on: :update, allow_blank: true
```

**settings_controller.rb**

```
  def update 
    @user = current_user

    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
        sign_in(@user, :bypass => true)
        flash[:success] = "Settings were successfully updated"

        respond_to do |format|
          format.html {redirect_to :action=> :show}
        end
    else
        flash[:fail] = "Settings **was not updated**"
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html {render :action => :show }
        end
    end
  end
```

Comment: there is a special method for `update_without_password`

Comment: @devanand thank you for answer, but unfortunately this doesn't work for me. My form contains password. And I want to update it if user fills this field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
  def update
    # For Rails 4
    account_update_params = devise_parameter_sanitizer.sanitize(:account_update)
    # For Rails 3
    # account_update_params = params[:user]

    # required for settings form to submit when password is left blank
    if account_update_params[:password].blank?
      account_update_params.delete("password")
      account_update_params.delete("password_confirmation")
    end

    @user = User.find(current_user.id)
    if @user.update_attributes(account_update_params)
      set_flash_message :notice, :updated
      # Sign in the user bypassing validation in case his password changed
      sign_in @user, :bypass => true
      redirect_to after_update_path_for(@user)
    else
      render "edit"
    end
  end
```

This is shameless copy-paste from devise wiki, it contains a lot of useful information that you can refer to - [wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Allow-users-to-edit-their-account-without-providing-a-password)

Answer (score 0):

I am also using devise and in the admin namespace having a users_controller inherited from application_controller, as I wanted to keep the admin and user section separate. 
The following thing worked for me.

In the User model

> validates :password, :password_confirmation, presence: true, on: :create

In update action of the controller

> `def update
>     # .....
>     @user.update_without_password(users_params)
>     # ......
>   end`